# Can you survive in a pub cellar for a week?

Tags: apocalypse, survival, isolation

This is for research for a kaiju horror story. I'm toying with it being set in an English pub cellar (like that of a Wetherspoons) as the surface is crawling with newly emerged kaiju, the plot progressing over the course of a few days. Apart from barrels of beer, what would be down there that could create a liveable environment i.e. food, water, heating, internet connection?

Comment: For a week, beer is all you need. It is actually highly nutritious. https://www.thespruceeats.com/beer-nutrition-information-353027 In England, no need for heat. It has very temperate weather. Do you seriously need Internet? Does your protagonist have a cell phone? The cellar would certainly have lighting, and therefore electricity.

Comment: A restroom with functioning water and sewer would be nice, especially after all that beer. For REAL Research, see Wells' *The War Of The Worlds* (1898), Book 2, Chapters I-V. It's the definitive work on trapped-in-ruins-while-monsters-roam-outside. A pub cellar is like a beachside vacation compared to the Ruined House.

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second: Lighting?  Not unless the power grid operators stay at their posts despite the monsters roaming the surface.  Maybe a survivalist pub owner kept an oil lamp or two in his cellar?

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, there will be the need for some hand waving in order to dismiss the fact that there are still working pumping stations to supply water under pressure to the taps, electricity to supply lights and the internet, cell tower service so you can call out on your phone, and even cooling so your beer stays cold. All the things usually taken for granted in disaster scenarios. Otherwise, the OP question about the 'internet connection' would be trivial.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond - make that an answer and you have my upvote.  The fact that  the character is living on beer will make him interesting to write as well.

Comment: Sounds pretty nice actually.

Answer (score 0):

For a week, beer is all you need. It is actually [highly nutritious](http://thespruceeats.com/beer-nutrition-information-353027). A beer and a vitamin pill and you are good to go. In England, no need for heat. It has very temperate weather. Do you seriously need Internet? Does your protagonist have a cell phone? The cellar would certainly have lighting, and therefore electricity, but this would take some hand waving in order to address the fact that there are still working pumping stations to supply water under pressure to the taps, electricity to supply lights and the internet, cell tower service so you can call out on your phone, and even cooling so your beer stays cold. All the things usually taken for granted in disaster scenarios. Otherwise, the OP question about the 'internet connection' would be trivial.

Comment: If it's an English pub, the beer isn't kept any colder than the cellar itself, so no worries there. ;-)

Comment: And there will probably also be soft drinks, packets of crisps, peanuts, pork scratchings, an ancient jar of pickled eggs....

Comment: @DrMcCleod And pickled eggs have a 'forever' shelf life. If you find a jar stuck in the very bottom n=back of your fridge ten years after you put it there, they are still edible. Well, as edible as pickled eggs ever were.